# With Knockoutjs choose a custom template for each item

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Given an array mapped in `knockout.js` and using [custom templates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html), how can one have each item in the array rendered using a different template?

Here is a link to [an example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmh_ca/QxVK6/1/) of the desired functionality - somewhat as one would hope it would be.

In simple terms, given an array like this:

```
people: ko.observableArray([
    { name: 'Rod', age: 123, template: 'personItem' },
    { name: 'IBM', incorporated: 1911, template: 'corporateItem' },
])
```

How can one set up a `foreach:` binding that uses one template for some items, and different templates for others.

(Note: I am aware that the use of underscore templates somewhat conflates the issue in question, and apologize for any unnecessary confusion.)

I have thought about using one template with a set of `if` bindings - one for each template type, like this:

```
<div data-bind='foreach: people'>
   <div data-bind='if: people.template() == "personItem"'>
   </div>
   <div data-bind='if: people.template() == "corporateItem"'>
   </div>
</div>
```

This seems quite inelegant, and I suspect (hope) there is a more elegant and fairly straightforward option.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated & thanks for reading.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Rather than passing a string to the `name` parameter of the `template` binding, you can actually pass a function to determine the template.  You would have to combine this with using the `foreach` option in your case rather than doing an "each" through your items.

So, your view model would look like:

```
var viewModel = {
    people: ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'Rod', age: 123, template: 'personItem' },
        { name: 'IBM', incorporated: 1911, template: 'corporateItem' },
    ]),
    getTemplate: function(item) {
        return item.template;   
    }
};
```

and your mark up would be like:

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: getTemplate, foreach: people }"></ul>

<script type="text/html" id="personItem">
        <li>
            <b data-bind="text: name"></b> is <%= age %> years old
        </li>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="corporateItem">
        <li>
            <b data-bind="text: name"></b> is <%= incorporated %> years old
        </li>
</script>
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/xF2xe/

Here is some additional reference material:

- http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/quick-tip-dynamically-changing.html
- http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_4_dynamically_choosing_which_template_is_used

Comment: Thank you so much. This is an excellent answer, and fabulous example.

Comment: An addendum to the question, I noted that one cannot change the template type dynamically i.e. as one would expect in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmh_ca/xF2xe/1/ -- I wonder if this is possible, or whether one must remove and replace an element of the array to change the template type.

Comment: It is actually trying to change your template.  However, it is running into an issue when running the template when it hits `incorporated`.  Here is an example where I replaced it with `$data.incorporated` in the template, as it will return null instead of an error.  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/xF2xe/2/

Comment: p.s. Your ThatConference was fabulous!

Comment: Thanks, it was a fun conference.